# R shiny strange behaviour of caching

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I am using `R shiny` and `ggplot2`.

My project layout looks like this:

```sh
global.R
server.R
ui.R
visualization.R
```

My `visualization.R`

```
image <- png::readPNG(source = '/path/mypng.png', native = FALSE)
ggplot(data = data) +
background_image(image)
```

Once I changed image path, image was changed as I was expected. When I am running `visualization.R` as a desktop app from `R studio` it works fine. But, when I am running Shiny's `server.R` file image is not updated. It always read same image, while image path is updated. I do not understand why.

In `R studio`, I also ran script `rm(list = ls())`

Any ideas ?

Thanks !

Comment: what is in global.R ? does it call visualization.R ?

Comment: global.R does not call visualization.R. It just contains packages, which must be installed.

Comment: So when is your "visualisation.R" called ?

Comment: server.R calls it. visualization.R itself contains image_path, but different (old image path) is loaded. I do not know what happened.

Comment: The server probably isn't checking to see if that file is changing. To force shiny-server to completely reload an app, add an empty text file named `restart.txt` in the same directory as ui.R, etc. This tells shiny-server to completely reload the app for the next user. If you need to update the image during a user's session, you should render it directly, and not depend on shiny to notice that a file changed during the session. If you need to force another full restart, you have to replace the `restart.txt` file. Shiny is looking at the timestamp.